What are suitable alternatives to getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() to prevent accidental user data loss?
For Context: The app I am working on is an admin app which is used to create and manage travel bookings for customers. This includes saving customers' personal information and payment information.
Concerned Platforms: macOS 15 and Windows 10

I am concerned that saving the app data directly in the Documents folder might pose a risk. Because people often interact with the Documents, they could inadvertently delete or move the folder.
But the flutter docs state:
Use this for files you don’t want exposed to the user. Your app should not use this directory for user data files.

The kind of data I am storing does come under "user data files", but I don't want to expose it to the user by placing it in such a commonly used directory. What would be the right approach in this scenario?
